# how to disappear a button after clicking on it in tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, button

consider the following code:

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.geometry('700x700')
frame=Frame(root)
frame.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=True)
def opencanvas():
    canvas=Canvas(frame,bg='red')
    canvas.place(x=50,y=50,height=300,width=300)
    button2=Button(frame,text='exit',command=canvas.place_forget)
    button2.place(x=5,y=10)
button1=Button(frame,text='open',command=opencanvas)
button1.place(x=5,y=10)
mainloop()
```

this program opens a frame in a tkinter window and a 'open' button in the frame.when pressing 'open',a canvas opens and a button named 'exit' appears in frame at the same place of the  open button.exit button hides canvas.

when clicking the 'exit' button,i want to disappear the 'exit' button automatically after performing its operation(ie,hiding canvas). what should i do to work this?

I want to insert some commands inside opencanvas() which disappears the button2 right after it pressed.

nb: the two buttons should place at same place and have same dimensions.

Comment: Why are you hiding the canvas instead of destroying it? Also why don't you make `canvas` and `button2` global variables and create a new function that hides/destroys them

Comment: Because i want to use the canvas repeatedly. And i want to hide the button only after it executes its operation. The function deletes the button before the button shows.

Comment: So make a function that calls `canvas.place_forget()` and `button2.place_forget()` and set that to `button2`'s command. For it to work you will need to make both `canvas` and `button2` global variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer for my question.It can be done by using lambda inside button command as follows.

```
button2=Button(frame,text='exit',command=lambda:[canvas.place_forget(),button2.place_forget()])
```

lambda function executes the commands one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Use `button1.place_forget()` or `.grid_forget()` or `.pack_forget()` depending on which geometry manager you use. If you use these, then the button is hidden. To get the button back use `.place()` etc...

If you want to, you could use `button1.destroy()` but this **deletes the button permanently**, and if you have to make that button again, you have to initialise from start.

Use `button.place_forget()` for your code to hide the button and then, `button1.place(x=5,y=10)` to show your button

Comment: I already tried these. But button2.place_forget() disappears button before it showing in the frame.

Comment: Don't use `place_forget()` as soon as you create a new button. Write it as a command for the button, so that when you click it, it gets hidden